# ExtJS Layout: Text and radiobuttons on the same line

Tags: extjs, layout

How can I make the 1st group radio buttons go a little bit up?
How can I make the 2nd group radio buttons go on the right of the text?

```
function sch26_json() {
    var json_data = {
        klonmode: trnd_form.getForm().findField('rb_klon').getGroupValue(),
        klonmode: trnd_form.getForm().findField('rb_tip_smetki').getGroupValue(),
        klon: trnd_form.getForm().findField('edit_klon').getValue(),
        name: (trnd_form.getForm().findField('dma16_cb_2').checked) ? '1' : '0',
        print: trnd_form.getForm().findField('rb_print').getGroupValue(),
        chif: r1
    };

    return Ext.JSON.encode(json_data);
}    

var sch26_button_function = function(btn) {
  if (btn.text == 'Справка') {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
         method: 'POST', 
            url: './src/sch26_report.php',
            jsonData: sch26_json(),
            success: function(response){
                var r = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                if (r.success == true) { 
               var fn = r.filename;
                    var spr_win = Ext.create('Trnd.SpravkaWindow', {
                        xtitle: 'Справка Синтетична Оборотна Ведомост',
                        xfilename: r.filename
                    });
                    spr_win.show(); 
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Внимание', r.errmsg);        
                };
            },
            failure: function(response){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Внимание', 'Грешка при стартиране на справката.');       
            }
        });
  } else if (btn.text == 'Отказ') {
    window.location = './main.php';
  }
}
var trnd_form = new Ext.form.Panel({ 
  frame: true, 
  title: 'Синтетична Оборотна Ведомост', 
  monitorValid: true,
  width: 300,
  height: 200,
  activeItem: 0,
  items: [
        {
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      border: false,
      items: [
              {xtype: 'displayfield', value: "Some text here <hr />"},
        ]
        },
     {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            columns: [150, 100],
            items: [
                {boxLabel: 'a', name: 'rb_klon', inputValue: 1, checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'b', name: 'rb_klon', inputValue: 2}
                        ]
    },
    {
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      border: false,
      items: [
              {xtype: 'displayfield', value: "Some text here"},
              {
              xtype: 'radiogroup', 
              items: [
                {boxLabel: 'a',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 1, checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'b',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 2},
                {boxLabel: 'c',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 3},
                {boxLabel: 'd',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 4}
                            ]
                            }

        ]
        }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
        id: 'button_spr',
      text    : 'Справка',
      handler : sch26_button_function
    }
     ]
});
```

It looks like this:
[image: How it looks]

This is how it should look like.
[image: How I want it to look]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'fieldLabel'property for radio group to get the label and radio buttons in one line.And you can define the height to display field to get the desired result.

Your code goes like below

```
 frame: true, 
  title: 'Синтетична Оборотна Ведомост', 
  monitorValid: true,
  width: 300,
  height: 200,
  renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
  activeItem: 0,
  items: [
        {
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      border: false,
      items: [
        {xtype: 'displayfield', height:20,  value: "Some text here <hr />"},
        ]
        },
     {
         xtype: 'radiogroup',
        height:20,
        columns: [150, 100],
            items: [
                {boxLabel: 'a', name: 'rb_klon', inputValue: 1, checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'b', name: 'rb_klon', inputValue: 2}
                        ]
    },
    {
      xtype: 'fieldset',
      border: false,
      items: [

              {
              xtype: 'radiogroup', 
                fieldLabel:'some Text Here',
              items: [
                {boxLabel: 'a',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 1, checked: true},
                {boxLabel: 'b',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 2},
                {boxLabel: 'c',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 3},
                {boxLabel: 'd',name: 'rb_tip_smetki',inputValue : 4}
                            ]
                            }

        ]
        }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
        id: 'button_spr',
      text    : 'Справка'

    }
     ]
```

Hope this helps you..